# Query to get percentage of how many customers live within a certain area

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have a x, y coord customer table and I need to find a percentage of how many customers live within a certain area or not which is (50,50)

query for anyone in test data less than 50:

```
SELECT X_Coord, Y_Coord
from customerlocation
count where (X_Coord < 50 or Y_Coord < 50)
```

anyone at 50:

```
SELECT X_Coord, Y_Coord
from customerlocation
count where (X_Coord = 50 or Y_Coord = 50)
```

How do I group these queries to get a percentage of who lives at the (50,50) and who lives inside the (50,50) range?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: The table has three columns - custid, X_coord, Y_Coord. Customer ID in test data is 1 -14. X and Y columns are random grid refs from (-50,-50) to (50,50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do separate counts for each requirement and divide by total count

```
select (a.count / count(*)) * 100, (b.count / count(*)) * 100
from 
(select count(*) as count
  from customerlocation where x_coord < 50 or y_coord < 50) as a,
(select count(*) as count
  from customerlocation where x_coord = 50 or y_coord = 50) as b,
customerlocation
```

Answer (score 0):

## MySql

**To count X,Y coord value :**

```
SELECT coord_name, count(*) total_count
FROM customerlocation
WHERE X_Coord < 50 OR (Y_Coord < 50)
GROUP BY X_Coord, Y_Coord
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select
cast(sum(A.lessthan50) as float)/cast((sum(A.lessthan50) + 
sum(A.anyoneat50)) as float)*100 lessthan50, 
cast(sum(A.anyoneat50) as float)/cast((sum(A.lessthan50) + 
sum(A.anyoneat50)) as float)*100 anyoneat50
from
(
select 
case when (x < 50  or y < 50) then 1 else 0 end as lessthan50,
case when (x = 50 or y = 50) then 1 else 0 end as anyoneat50
from cordinates
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest method:

```
select avg( (X_Coord = 50 or Y_Coord = 50) )
from customerlocation
where X_Coord <= 50 or Y_Coord <= 50;
```

This can be a little tricky to see, so here is a slightly more verbose alternative:

```
select sum( (X_Coord = 50 or Y_Coord = 50) ) / sum( (X_Coord < 50 or Y_Coord < 50) )
from customerlocation
where X_Coord <= 50 or Y_Coord <= 50;
```